# How to check/verify Git repository which uses submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules, fsck

It seems that

```
git fsck
```

doesn't check any submodules (that is, verify that submodules do not have corrupted files). Seeing that

```
git fsck --recursive
```

is not not supported either. What's the correct way to check the whole repository hierarchy?

The best I can think of would be

```
git fsck --no-dangling --full && git submodule foreach --recursive git fsck --no-dangling --full && echo OK
```

but is that enough and can we have something simpler?

Comment: That's pretty much it. You aren't supposed to *have* to run `git fsck` so there's no real effort to make it simple and convenient.